# jQuery download a zipfile from a button?

Tags: jquery, button, zip

Quite embarrassing how much time I spend trying to get to download a zipfile from a button....

```
<button type='button' id='button-download'>download zipfile</button>


$("#button-download").live("click", function() {
    $.get("http://localhost/admin/zip/002140.zip"); // doesn't work?
})
```

I need something bullet proof here, that's why I ask here, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a plain:

```
<a href="http://localhost/admin/zip/002140.zip" id="button-download">download zipfile</a>
```

link. Then it'll work fine (“bullet proof” even) without JavaScript available. It also offers more of the traditional affordances users might expect from a download link, such as right-click-save-as, or drag-and-drop.

You can of course use CSS to make it look like a button instead of a link. But what it *actually* is, is a link. So that's how it should be marked up.

Comment: Thanks I am using this as the backup under "problems downloading?" It's in JavaScript but it's an admin panel and my users need JavaScript enabled anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

You should set the `location.href` property to cause navigation:

```
$("#button-download").live("click", function() {
  location.href = "http://localhost/admin/zip/002140.zip";
});
```

You could also have a simple `<a>` element, styled as if it were a button, in that way even the users who have JavaScript disabled will be able to download the file.

Comment: Gee, location.href, it's time to go to bed!

Comment: Actually I have a problem, when using this or also window.location I am loosing my DOM created by jQuery. That's not an issue though what's worse the page goes -1, like hitting the back button? WTF??

Comment: If you're visiting here from 5 years after this post, `.live()` got removed in jquery 1.9, so use `.on()`. (thanks PaparazzoKid below)

Answer (score 1):

That is sending an AJAX request.

I haven't tried this, but it should work in theory. If you try to go to a location of a file that is downloaded, it prompts you to download rather than take you to that page.

```
<button type='button' id='button-download'>download zipfile</button>


$("#button-download").live("click", function() {
    window.location = "http://localhost/admin/zip/002140.zip";
})
```

Comment: For future surfers, instead of `.live()` use `.on()`. `.live()` was removed in jQuery 1.9.

Answer (score 1):

Bit late to the party but thought I'd share my solution as nobody else has.

You can have the best of both worlds; a simple HTML link and a JS function, without losing the non-JS users.

```
<a id="download" href="http://www.example.com/download.zip">Download</a>

$("#download").on("click", function(e) {

    // cancel the link's original functionality
    e.preventDefault();

    // do something before downloading
    alert("Thanks for downloading!");

    // download file
    location.href = "http://www.example.com/download.zip";

});
```